# AutoHotKey SetFormat works only at the first time?

Tags: autohotkey

I found SetFormat only works at the first time, like the following simplified script:

```
Var = 0.0

f1::
SetFormat, float,03
Var += 1
msgbox, %Var%
return
```

I only get 001 at the first time. After that, it only displays 2, 3, ... for each f1. Anything I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In...

```
Var += 1
```

Var is getting cast to an integer.  Try:

```
Var += 1.0
```